# How to integrate ScalaCheck and IntelliJ (10.5 or 11)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Is there anyway to integrate [ScalaCheck](http://code.google.com/p/scalacheck/) and the testing infrastructure [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. The best way to do that is to use [specs2](http://specs2.org), or [ScalaTest](http://scalatest.org).

Comment: See the Checkers trait of ScalaTest - http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/writing_scalacheck_style_properties

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to integrate scala-check and the testing infrastructure provided by IntelliJ is by wrapping it with scala-test.

This will require the following scala-test dependency:

```
org.scalatestplus:scalacheck
```

More information can be found [here](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/writing_scalacheck_style_properties) and a working sample can be found [here](https://github.com/MarcoLotz/taskmanager-scala/blob/main/src/test/scala/com/marcolotz/taskmanager/core/datacontainers/AbstractProcessCollectorTest.scala)